# REST or SOAP call?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, crm

I have few calls made to a CRM application using http from my application. I need to know is it through SOAP or REST. Will I be able to know if it is through REST or SOAP using the url? Or is there a way to find how to determine the protocol. Code snippet is as follows:

```
HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet(url);
request.setParams(/*some HttpParams*/);


ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new UnicodeResponseHandler();
String response = httpClient.execute(request, responseHandler);

/* where httpClient is an instance of org.apache.http.client.HttpClient */
/* where url is a http url */
```

Comment: I don't see no SOAP anywhere. But there is not REST in sight, too.

Comment: Thats what im confused. How to determine it seeing the code?

Comment: Usually you'd be given a WSDL to understand how to interact with a SOAP service.

Comment: I believe the appliaction doesn't use any wsdl

Comment: CRM has a SOAP calls with and without a WSDL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509052.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Basically `HttpClient` can be used for making both REST and SOAP calls, check [this link](http://polimetla.com/2011/04/27/consuming-web-service-using-apache-httpclient-and-soap-message/) for SOAP call usage.

The main difference lies in the way you are making the *request* and parsing the *response*.

Comment: can you please provide an example... Or give me hint to where to look to determine whether it is REST or SOAP.

Comment: Check this article for making SOAP call using HttpClient - _http://polimetla.com/2011/04/27/consuming-web-service-using-apache-httpclient-and-soap-message/_

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly confused by the question. There are a couple of different way to query Crm. REST with OData, SOAP with a WSDL, SOAP without a WSDL.

You could tell the difference from the Url pretty easily, because there are different SOAP and REST endpoints. Have a look under Settings > Customisations > Developer Resources.

[image]

I dont really understand this situation where you are about to use one (or both?) dynamically, because usage of each is quite different.

If this is just a general question about CRM 2011 SOAP & REST I would suggest having a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490659.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

that is REST, you are creating an http get and setting HTTP parameters (which excludes soap) and getting a response. The response can be a plain old string,json, or xml...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such way.

If you're lucky - the URL will return you WSDL in case this is SOAP web service,
but this is not mandatory.
You might try to add "`?wsdl`" to the URL- but once again, this is a convention of some SOAP web service framework of Java —
But still not mandatory according to the spec.

SOAP payload is based on XML, so if the URL returns something that its content type is not "application/xml" you might assume this is REST web service.
In addition, SOAP works with POST methods only, while REST is using GET, and other HTTP methods as well - PUT and DELETE.

In you code for example, you're using a GET method so we might think this is RESTFul web service, but who said this is not a bug in your code, and you actually need to use POST here?
But once again - this method is not safe as RESTFul web service may return data in XML format.

You will have to implement some discovery mechanism, or maybe to configure your application with set host/IP addresses of your services and for each one of them determine in the configuration if this is SOAP or REST.

Comment: REST services can also return XML - the content type is separate to the architecture.

Comment: Indded, and I have mentioned it in my comment - see "as RESTFul web service may return data in XML format", of course you can also send payload with this format.